# Quickbooks online API Wrapper

Tags: php, api, wrapper, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

Looking to connect my online shopping cart to my Quickbooks Online Plus account. I am looking for some sort of PHP Wrapper for doing this, if possible. I have searched the internet and found nothing recent. All posts/questions/answers date back to 2010 at best, and none of the answers seem to work.

Does anyone know where I can find the current documentation, a php wrapper, or a customer service number for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm the author of the [QuickBooks PHP DevKit](https://code.intuit.com/sf/projects/php_devkit/) that Narcissus mentioned.

I'm not exactly sure where you guys are looking that you're seeing the latest posts in 2010, but... I post regularly in two places:
 [ConsoliBYTE forums](http://consolibyte.com/forum/) (our company forums)
 [Intuit Developer Forums](https://idnforums.intuit.com/) (I'm Keith57- you'll see a lot of posts from me)

The latest SVN commits to the PHP DevKit were made yesterday (November 1st), so the project is still very much maintained, updated, and recent. There are posts on the forums from within the last few days too.

The PHP DevKit provides PHP APIs for:

- QuickBooks for Windows
- QuickBooks Online Edition

And offers two flavors, depending on what you're building:

- a qbXML interface (if you're building one-off integrations)
- an IPP/IDS interface (if you're building SaaS applications for the Intuit Partner Platform)

It's usually pretty easy to use- there are docs in the docs/ folder of the library, and if you get stuck you can ask for help on the forums.

The code is fully open-source- you can download nightly builds, releases, or get subversion access if you sign up for an account at [code.intuit.com](https://code.intuit.com/sf/projects/php_devkit/).

You mentioned that you're integrating a shopping cart, so I'll also mention this- we provide connectors for many common shopping carts already built ([QuickBooks Connector for OpenCart, Infusionsoft, WHMCS, FoxyCart, and more!](https://secure.consolibyte.com))- you sign up with us, plug in some values, and *poof* orders from your shopping cart flow automatically into QuickBooks.

We also offer commercial support/consulting if you get really stuck and don't want to wait for an answer on the forums.

[5](https://secure.consolibyte.com):

Comment: FWIW, Keith, the reason I was saying 2010 was because of the most recent posting under 'Project News' at https://code.intuit.com/sf/projects/php_devkit/ . Also, thanks for an awesome library.

Comment: This is perfect. I came across this previously, but at a different URL, and when attempting to download it, I received a 404 error. Thanks so much for the kit, and your response.

Comment: Anyone know where I register an app for the Web Connector? Every option I see, only allows me to create an app for the "App Center". I need a private integration.

Comment: If you're using the Web Connector, you DO NOT NEED to register. If you're building a SaaS application for QuickBooks desktop or QuickBooks Online, you create an app at http://appcenter.intuit.com. If you're building a qbXML app for QuickBooks Online or QuickBooks Merchant Services, you register at https://appreg.intuit.com/

Comment: code.intuit.com is gone. PHP Devkit has moved to http://consolibyte.com/downloads/quickbooks-php-devkit/

Comment: GitHub link too: https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you checked out <strike>https://code.intuit.com/sf/projects/php_devkit/, whose last post was early 2010.</strike>  **Updated link:** https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

Though it doesn't seem to have been updated lately, I used this project before it fell under the actual code.intuit.com 'banner' and was amazed at how useful it was, as well as how many problems it automatically solved.

There's a lot of niggly issues that you will come across as far as making sure that certain things exist before others do: the library above tracks what needs to happen in it's own database so ensures the 'order of operations' while also letting you assign your own IDs to it... allowing you to almost transparently use your IDs and automatically being mapped to and from the QB ID.

Good luck with it :)